# Invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting the following error on an Entity Framework Core MVC app. Can anyone help with why? I'm including simplified versions of my Models below.

> InvalidOperationException: The expression 'b.BrandId' is invalid
> inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property
> access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived
> types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as'
> operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation
> access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending),
> ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.

I have a Products table and a Brands table. Brands are unique and Products can only have one Brand, but there can be many Products for a single Brand.

The Products model and Brand model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int BrandId { get; set; } 
    
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Brand = new Brand();
    }
}

public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my ProductsController this is what throws the above error. The include Brand part is so I can show the BrandName on my Index page and it is there that the error can be traced to:

```
// GET: Products
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Products.Include(b => b.Brand)
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreatedDate)
        .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Probably you have a typo in your original code. According to the error message you have put `b.BrandId` in your `.Include`, not `b.Brand`.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment was enough to make me look again and see my error - see my comment on the response marked as the answer.

Comment: You should remove that `Brand` initialization from your `Product` constructor, otherwise the properties of `Brand` will not be set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your classes are not properly configured and don't create any constructor:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public int BrandId { get; set; } 
     [ForeignKey(nameof(BrandId))]
     [InverseProperty("Products")]
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}

public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Product.Brand))]
    public virtual  ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error with my classes like this.

Comment: @mjuk You have to delete everything and make new migration since dbcontext is changed now. After this you can try your query.

Comment: Thank you! I recreated the DB again but a silly error - I have two Product Controllers, one inside an Admin area and I pasted the line from the non Admin one by mistake. Coincidentally the line numbers were 26 in one and 27 in the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to share my solution with a similar error on a ICollection

My Error

```cs
// My error here was my collection, because it is a field

public ICollection<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
```

Solution

```
// I just had to make it as a Property

public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
```

Took me a while to find my little error...
But now the error is really explicit for me

> since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

Comment: Also important, because it took me quite some time to figure this out: I had a property but it had only a getter. Something like `public Product? Product { get;  } = null;` While it is a property, the missing setter causes the property access error. Add the setter and then you can use `ThenInclude`