# EF Core 5 "is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use EF Core for a many-to-many relationship. I follow this guide: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx and I have this :

`DBPizza` model class:

```
public class DBPizza
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    public List<DBPizzaIngredient> PizzaIngredients { get; set; }
}
```

`DBIngredient` model class:

```
public class DBIngredient
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<DBPizzaIngredient> PizzaIngredients { get; set; }
}
```

And the `DBPizzaIngredient` class:

```
public class DBPizzaIngredient
{
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
    public DBPizza Pizza { get; set; }

    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public DBIngredient Ingredient {get; set; }
}
```

There is my `DbContext`:

```
public class DataContext: DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DBPizzaIngredient>().HasKey(pi => new { pi.PizzaId, pi.IngredientId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DBPizzaIngredient>()
                    .HasOne<DBPizza>(pi => pi.Pizza)
                    .WithMany(pizza => pizza.PizzaIngredients)
                    .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.PizzaId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<DBPizzaIngredient>()
                    .HasOne<DBIngredient>(pi => pi.Ingredient)
                    .WithMany(ingredient => ingredient.PizzaIngredients)
                    .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.IngredientId);
    }

    public DbSet<DBUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DBPizza> Pizzas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DBIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DBPizzaIngredient> PizzaIngredients { get; set; }
}
```

And the code where I have an issue:

```
public async Task<List<DBPizza>> Pizzas()
{
    return await _dataContext.Pizzas
                             .Include(pizza => pizza.PizzaIngredients)
                             .ThenInclude(pi => pi.PizzaId)
                             .ToListAsync();
}
```

I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'pi.PizzaId' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

I read this topic: [Invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229722/invalid-inside-an-include-operation-since-it-does-not-represent-a-property-ac), but it didn't resolved my issue

Comment: Why do you want to include PizzaId? It's not a related entity. `Include()` is to load related entities.

Comment: Indeed it's that ... thank you !