# The expression 'tp.Tag_Posts.AsQueryable().Select(t => t.Tag)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity

Tag and Post have many-to-many relationship;
I try get all tags in a Post :

```
var post = _postRepository.GetSingle(p => p.Id == id, c => c.Category, u => u.User,tp=>tp.Tag_Posts.Select(t=>t.Tag));
```

GenericRepository :

```
public TEntity GetSingle(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
{
     var query = _dbSet.Where(condition);

     return includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty)).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And I get the error :

> The expression 'tp.Tag_Posts.AsQueryable().Select(t => t.Tag)' is
> invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a
> property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared
> on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the
> 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection
> navigation access can be filtered by composing Where,
> OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For
> more information on including related data

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229722/invalid-inside-an-include-operation-since-it-does-not-represent-a-property-ac

Comment: It seems you should read the documentation for [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager). Also think about your `TEntity` - what property would represent a collection of `Tag`s?